# Nuisance neighbor shining green laser light into my bedroom window

Tags: texas, tenant

Does anyone know if its illegal to shine a green laser light into someone's bedroom in the state of Texas?

I know its illegal to shine it on police officers, but it seems other citizens are open game to this nuisance?

Would it also possibly fall under some harassment law if it happens repeatedly the way it already has?